# Trac Reporting export Change history with date time

Tags: mysql, reporting, trac

am trying to export alle the change history of all my trac tickets via a tab delimited text file export. 
I successed so far with the following SQL Statement:

```
SELECT 

id AS Ticket,
tc.author as author,
tc.field as field, 
tc.newvalue as comments_new
from ticket t
LEFT JOIN ticket_change tc ON ( t.id=tc.ticket )
```

But I need also the time and date of each entry. There is a field time in the table ticket_change but it is only the time without the date. 
Seems like I have to use some functions within the SQL to get what I need. Can anybody help me to get there?

Every Help is very appreciated. 
Best Regards
Ali

Comment: An example im Mysql how to display the time differents between datetime now and the one in the change_table would also help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The [time](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/DatabaseSchema/TicketSystem#Tableticket_change) field is an integer representing epoch microseconds. You can use the Trac utility `trac.util.datefmt.from_utimestamp` to convert the value to `datetime` format. That only helps if you are working in Python though. In other languages, you can use recipes for converting from [unix seconds](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/convert-epoch-seconds-to-the-current-time-date). Note you must divide the value in Trac by 1e6 first, to convert from microseconds to seconds.

Comment: Hi @RjOllos thank you for your answer. Currently I have only access to MySQL so the Pyhton way is not possible.I tried following statement but it is not working because of syntaxs <br/>  <pre>  'SELECT 

id AS Ticket,
tc.author as author,
tc.field as field,
(select(FROM_UNIXTIME(tc.time, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i')))  as time,  
tc.newvalue as comments_new
from ticket t
LEFT JOIN ticket_change tc ON ( t.id=tc.ticket ) <code>  <br/>'

Comment: I get the following when I try to use FROM_UNIXTIME Report execution failed: no such function: FROM_UNIXTIME

Comment: You'll have to check your MySQL version and then consult the documentation to see if that function is available.

Comment: THANK YOU for reporting what I couldn't figure out: that the times are stored in _microseconds_, so you have to divide them by 1e6. None of the examples I found showed that, and without it `from_unixtime(time)` always returns NULL.